# How can I get data from MediaWiki API if the title doesn't exactly match?

Tags: match, mediawiki, sql-like, wikipedia-api

I am trying to get some information from different Wikipedia pages but in the MediaWiki result I don't get the data from the page if the title I use in my query doesn't exactly match the title of the page. Is there any way to get the best match for this title? Maybe something like the SQL LIKE operator?

Here is one example. With titles="Sankt-Jacobikirche" I don't get the page I'm looking for.

http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&titles=Sankt-Jacobikirche&exintro=1&inprop=url

Sometimes at least I get the correct title so I can do a new request and get the correct page like with titles="Sankt-Jacobikirche_(Hamburg)"

http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&titles=Sankt-Jacobikirche_(Hamburg)&exintro=1&inprop=url

And get the correct page with the title I get in the REDIRECT or Normalized section, like it happens with the correct title: titles="Sint-Jacobikerk (Hamburg)"

How can I get this final data starting from titles="Sankt-Jacobikirche" ?

Comment: I think searching for all pages starting with that name is usually not very useful. Most of the time, if the correct article is “X (some disambiguation)”, then the article “X” also exists. If it doesn't, there's no need for the disambiguation. I think the article you're mentioning is an exception, not a rule.

Comment: Actually it happens with many places I am searching for. Now If I get an empty result I do a new request like this one:
http://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Sankt-Jacobikirche (Hamburg)
So if the result of this call is not empty I try again with the new title but there are still many times where this result is empty

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this and I still can't solve it but if someone else has this kind of problems with Wikipedia API I suggest him to have a look on www.freebase.com and their API.

Comment: @Txaku, not gonna fly Freebase has been merged to Wikidata so the MediaWiki web API is the way to access it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what you're trying to achieve, but as svick says guessing the title is an exception, not the rule.

You need to first get the correct title either by [title search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) or by [full text search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search).